# Entropy of a spatially and temporally varying fluid system?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to analyze the change in system thermodynamic entropy of an ideal gas system.

For reference, I'm analyzing solution techniques for solving the 1D compressible Euler equations:
$$
\partial_t \rho + \partial_x (\rho u_x) = 0\\
\partial_t (\rho u_x) + \partial_x (\rho u_x^2 + P) = 0\\
\partial_t e + \partial_x ((e + P) u_x) = 0\\
e = \frac{P}{\gamma - 1} + \frac{1}{2} \rho u_x^2\\
\partial_t (\rho s) + \partial_x  (\rho s u_x) = \dot{S}_{gen}
$$

The first test problem I want to analyze is the classical shock tube configuration where the jump discontinuity is located at $x=0$:
$$
\rho_L = 1\\
P_L = 1\\
\rho_R = 4\\
P_R = 4\\
u_x(t=0) = 0\\
\gamma = \frac{5}{3}
$$

To get an idea of what I should expect, I computed the analytical solution for this problem (using Toro's Riemann Solvers book), and computed the entropy as
$$
\frac{\rho s - S_0}{c_v} = \ln\left(\frac{P}{P_0} \left(\frac{\rho_0}{\rho}\right)^\gamma\right)
$$
where my understanding is that $\rho_0$, $P_0$, and $S_0$ are user-chosen reference values. I decided to chose $\rho_{0} = 4$, $P_0 = 4$, and $\frac{S_0}{c_v} = 1$, though this doesn't necessarily effect the final result. Here's the entropy density at two times $t=0$ and $t=1$:

[image]

As a sanity check I defined the domain $x \in [-4, 4]$ and tried to integrate $\rho s$ over the domain and compared this to the initial system entropy:

$$
\left.\int^4_{-4} \rho s dx\right|_{t=1} - \left.\int^4_{-4} \rho s dx\right|_{t=0} = -0.477216
$$

This would be acceptable if there was mass flow out of the domain boundaries, but I chose the domain such that the shock and rarefaction fronts don't reach the domain boundaries. This seems to imply that
$$
\int^1_0 \int^4_{-4} \dot{S}_{gen} dx dt = -0.477216
$$
which is only possible if $\dot{S}_{gen} < 0$ somewhere in the domain, a clear violation of the 2nd law of Thermodynamics. However, my understanding is that the Euler equations should obey the 2nd law.

My question is how do I resolve this issue? How should you use the 2nd law to analyze the entropy flow/generation of a spatially and temporally varying fluid field (both analytically, as well as for CFD simulations)?

Here's a plot of $u_x$ at $t=1$ for reference:

[image]

Comment: Do your profiles of P, rho, v have a shock wave traveling one way, rarefaction wave traveling the other, e.g., like in a standard solution for a Sod shock tube problem, e.g., youtube.com/watch?v=kU6hMmwHxBo -?

Comment: Yes, the shock is traveling to the left, as is the contact discontinuity, and the rarefaction fan is traveling to the right.

Comment: I would expect the entropy to be increased in all shocked gas, in your picture it is between ≈−1.7 and =0. But what we see in the picture, it drops to the unshocked level at ≈−0.5. That's strange. Why does it happen in your calculation? The profiles of $\rho$ and $P$ don't have anything special at that location $x \approx -0.5$, then how come your formula for the entropy produced a change at that location?

Comment: I found my issue. My entropy equation of state is incorrect. It should really be $\frac{s - s0}{c_v} = \ln\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\left(\frac{\rho_0}{\rho}\right)^\gamma\right)$, so what I was plotting as my "entropy density" is actually more representative of the specific entropy, which integrating over the domain obviously has little meaning. Integrating the corrected entropy density function produces a net positive entropy generation in my domain.

Comment: So with the correct entropy equation you find that entropy is increased in the whole range between $x=0$ and the shock front position, and elsewhere it is not affected?

Comment: With the fixed EOS, entropy is increasing between the shock front and the contact discontinuity (which is moving to the left at about u*=-0.5), and everywhere else it's isentropic.